# Spherical metric multiply by a function

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I know that if I want to get the metric for a two sphere I consider a Cartesian flat space, I change to spherical coordinates and then I consider that the radio is constant (so the space is not flat anymore) so I get this metric:

$$a(d\theta^2+\sin^2 \theta d\phi^2)$$

the thing is, if I have a metric like that but which is multiplied by a function $f(θ,ϕ)$ (differentiable on $S^2$), this new metric describe an sphere but I don´t know why... Someone can help?

$$f(θ,ϕ)(d\theta^2+\sin^2 \theta d\phi^2)$$

Comment: $a\;\mathrm d\Omega^2\to f(\theta,\phi)\mathrm d\Omega^2$ is called a [conformal map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_geometry) (which is a diffeomorphism)

Comment: In two dimensions, your statement is true -- multiplying the metric by an arbitary function does not change the curvature.  In any other dimension (other than 1, where curvature is not defined, I guess), you do change the curvature tensor, and the mapping is not an isomorphism.