# Metric defining an sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature, mathematics

I want to find for which cases this metric can define an sphere:
$$\frac{1}{P^2}\left(\mathrm d\theta^2+\sin^2 \theta\; \mathrm d\phi^2\right)$$
where $P=\sin^2 \theta+K\cos^2 \theta$, with $K$ the gaussian curvature (constant).

I know from the post [Spherical metric multiply by a function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238432/spherical-metric-multiply-by-a-function) that the curvature doesn't change if you multiply the metric by a differentiable function, so I suppose
that the only condition is that $K$ has to be positive, right?

Comment: May I ask why would you choose to post this here instead of [math.se]? This question has no physical content.